# Removing text from a fasta gene name between two characters

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta, sequence-alignment

I have a large codon alignment that has a variety of gene names in the headers. The headers are in the following format:

```
>ENST00000357033.DMD.-1 | CODON | REFERENC
```

I want to modify all of the headers in the fasta to exclude all characters after the first "." and before the first "|". Desired outcome:

```
>ENST00000357033 | CODON | REFERENC
```

I've tried a few sed commands, no dice. Any advice? I'm averse to using awk, since I'd like to keep the formatting of the alignment and awk scares me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^>/s/\.[^ ]* / /'
```

for each line starting with a '>' replace 'dot' followed by some char different from spaces followed by a space, by a space.

Answer (score 1):

no neeed to be scared by `awk`:

```
mawk NF=NF FS='[.][^ ]+' OFS=    

>ENST00000357033 | CODON | REFERENC
```